# Cannot process test roots and app roots in the same compilation unit Hilt Android

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I get this build error:

```
Cannot process test roots and app roots in the same compilation unit:
```

When I am trying to write the instrumented test like this:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class DataRecognitionRepositoryImplTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Test
    fun first() {

    }

}
```

I have also created my own runner like this:

```
class HiltTestRunner: AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(
        cl: ClassLoader?,
        className: String?,
        context: Context?
    ): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }

}
```

And set it like:

```
 testInstrumentationRunner "com.mayurg.helpers.HiltTestRunner"
```

My root build file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried searching a lot but did not find anything useful apart from this: https://dagger.dev/hilt/flags

But I am not sure how/where to use these. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to add this to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.arguments['dagger.hilt.disableCrossCompilationRootValidation'] = 'true'

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `@AndroidEntryPoint` on your **activity**. If you are using **application** class, make sure to add `@HiltAndroidApp` and add the class on **AndroidManifest**.